# PostgreSQL: creating several pgplsql procedures in a batch

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a PHP-script with several similar SQL tables (only 1 column varies):

```
define('SQL_TABLES', '
create table hide_id (
        ID       varchar(20) references quincytrack,
        USERNAME varchar(20) not null,
        UPDATED  timestamp default current_timestamp
);
create table hide_name (
        NAME     varchar(20) not null,
        USERNAME varchar(20) not null,
        UPDATED  timestamp default current_timestamp
);
create table hide_category (
        CATEGORY varchar(120) not null,
        USERNAME varchar(20) not null,
        UPDATED  timestamp default current_timestamp
);
create table hide_appsversion (
        APPSVERSION varchar(30) not null,
        USERNAME varchar(20) not null,
        UPDATED  timestamp default current_timestamp
);
create table hide_osversion (
        OSVERSION varchar(30) not null,
        USERNAME varchar(20) not null,
        UPDATED  timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

And I'd like to create an upsert procedure for each of them:

```
define('SQL_PROCS', '
create or replace function hide_id_upsert(
        _ID       varchar,
        _USERNAME varchar
        ) returns void as $BODY$
        begin
                update hide_id set
                        ID       = _ID,
                        USERNAME = _USERNAME,
                        UPDATED  = current_timestamp
                where ID = _ID;

                if not found then
                        insert into hide_id (
                                ID,
                                USERNAME
                        ) values (
                                _ID,
                                _USERNAME
                        );
                end if;
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
');
```

I wonder, if I could do it in a batch by PgPlSQL or PHP means. Something like:

```
$columns = array('ID', 'NAME', 'CATEGORY', 'APPSVERSION', 'OSVERSION');
foreach ($columns as $key) {
   $sth = $pg->prepare(sprintf(SQL_PROCS_TEMPLATE, $key, $key, ...);
   $sth->execute();
}
```

but without the above ugliness of having to specify **$key** numerous times.

Using PostgreSQL 8.4.5 and PHP 5.1.6 under CentOS 5.5 Linux

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't see you using `%s` anywhere in the string for your `sprintf`, but if you want to use the same variable multiple times in the same `sprintf` string, you can use `%1$s` for the first argument, like this:

```
sprintf('%1$s %1$s', 'hubba') // hubba hubba
```

Edit: here's the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php. Of course, this is not very PostgreSpecific, but I hope it is what you're looking for.

EDIT: So, in your case, you would do:

```
define('SQL_PROCS', '
create or replace function %1$s_upsert(
        _ID       varchar,
        _USERNAME varchar
        ) returns void as $BODY$
        begin
                update %1$s set
                        ID       = _ID,
                        %2$s = _%2$s,
                        UPDATED  = current_timestamp
                where ID = _ID;

                if not found then
                        insert into %1$s (
                                ID,
                                %2$s
                        ) values (
                                _ID,
                                _%2$s
                        );
                end if;
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
');

$columns = array('ID', 'NAME', 'CATEGORY', 'APPSVERSION', 'OSVERSION');
foreach ($columns as $key) {
   $sth = $pg->prepare(sprintf(SQL_PROCS, 'hide_' . strtolower($key), $key));
   $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, I've updated my question to make it clearer. Maybe a nicer solution is possible...

Comment: How's this? It uses 2 arguments for the sprintf to account for the lowercase table names and uppercase columns. (also, it is missing a closing paren, which I'm adding in 2 seconds. There we go.)